# web interface tool for mysql administration

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I want simple web interface tool for client to insert in MySQL table.
I use phpmyadmin but I need another tool being more simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)
It's a java based tool and runs on all platform and connect to most of the databases(for which you have a JDBC driver)

You can install it using

```
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/
```